# How to use Angular 4 with SASS

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli

I'm starting my first project using `Angular4` and `sass` and I'm trying to figure it out how to work with `sass` the proper way. I'm using `angular-cli` and already set the default style to use `scss` syntax. I also already defined the compilation, etc.

However I saw that we have an option styleUrls on the component, where in some cases we define styles used only in that component.

The problem is, when I set a `scss` file in that `component` it's not generating it's own `.css` file neither being included in the main `.css` file, generated from the root project.

So basically I have a project structure like this:

```
app
    app.module.ts
    app.routing.ts
    home
        home.component.ts
        home.html
        _home.scss
    client
        client.component.ts
        client.html
        _client.scss
scss
    _imports.scss
    colors
        _colors.scss
    ui
        _button.scss
        _table.scss
    //.. more folder and files
styles.scss
index.html
```

And I'd like to be able to set the main `css` style within the `styles.scss` file, which will be inserted into the `index.html` file later, on the build process. But also be able to generate a single `css` file for each component I have, e.g. `home` and `client`, and only use those `css` styles within their own `component`.

Is it possible to do it? I've tried to do it and I didn't find any other resource about this!

Comment: from what I understand the encapsulated css is bundled inside of the main.bundle.js, then when the app loads itll append the styles to the head tag (in a separate style tag from the main styles). Are your styles not loaded at all?

Comment: @LLai Yes, they are, but only the main style file `style.css`. But for example, the files home.scss and client.scss never compile into .css and because of this, never get inject.

Comment: odd, can you re install your node modules. Maybe one of the loaders is messed up

Comment: Here you know how usually things work and you are doing the same. But for some reason they are working fine. You added `styles.scss` to `.angular-cli` , still in the final build its not getting reflected in your page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [**import directive**](http://vanseodesign.com/css/sass-the-import-directive/):

```
@import "styles.scss";  
@import "css/styles.scss";  
@import url("http://example.com/css/styles.scss");
```

This imports the CSS from the other CSS files into the main CSS file, appending the contents of each file to the main file based on the order that you choose to insert them.

Note that you **do not** need the `.scss` file extension, as SASS will handle that automatically, and you can simply import with `@import "file"`. And you also don't need to specify each file with an independent import, as you can combine them all in a single import:

```
@import "styles.scss", "css/styles.scss", url("http://example.com/css/styles.scss");
```

You can also do nested imports by specifying the `@import` within a selector:

```
.global-nav {  
  @import "nav-bkgd";
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I don't know if I made myself clear, but the main issue is not impoting the files, but compiling them. For example, in the question, the files _home.scss and _client.scss never gets compiled into pure .css. Or am I missing something within your answer?

Comment: My apologies. However, there's no reason why they shouldn't compile. Simply reference them as  `/app/home/_home.scss` and `/app/client/_client.scss` respectively. You may find that you need to clear your cache; try holding `SHIFT` while clicking the refresh icon.

Comment: They are getting compiled but it's injected into head with style attribute only when that component is used.

Answer (score 5):

In an Angular 4.4+ with ng-cli, you only need to change the the following settings in `.angular-cli.json`

```
{
  ...
  "apps": [
    ...
    "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      ...
  ]
  ...
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

and in each Component, if necessary, change `.css` to `.scss`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-your-component',
    styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: but scss needs to be compiled, where do you define that ? it's not just an extension ...

Answer (score 2):

You can specify scss when you create project.

```
ng new project-name --style scss
```

Comment: Like I said in the question, I already did it. It's not the problem.

Comment: Sorry for missed that. Is your styleUrls of home component looks like `styleUrls: ['./_home.scss']`?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, i have a leftnav component and its scss seemed  to be never compiled , i tried all the above but didnt work , and i tried to creat new app using ng  new ....  but after that i got it fixed by changing my thoughts :D

seems like we cant use `same component selector` inside its relative .scss file 
but instead we should use a wrapping div with suitable className , and use that .className as a root wrapping of .scss file content.

let me demonstrate, this is my app:

```
app/component/leftnav
  |leftnav.scss
  |leftnav.html ==> simply `left nav works!`
  |leftnav.ts ==> selector leftnav
app/
  |app.html
  |app.scss
```

and inside the old leftnav.scss

```
leftnav{
    background:red;
}
```

and inside app.html

```
<leftnav></leftnav>
```

and how i got it fixed ! as i said by adding a wrapping div with classname `.leftnav` inside `leftnav.html` and use its as root wrapping of my leftnav.scss instead of component selector

so my new

```
.leftnav{
    background:red; 
}
```

and it works !

Answer (score 0):

If you have an already wokring project `ng new my-sassy-app --style=scss`
 won't help so you need to use `ng set defaults.styleExt scss`
 this changes `angular.cli.json` file as

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "scss",
  "component": {
 }
}
```

Now change the already present `css` files to `scss` extension you should see that `scss` is now working.Don't forget to change the `css` extensions in your component definations to `scss`
[The source](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli)